# Where is Plugin Data Stored in the Database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm setting up multi-site for the latest version of wordpress. I got two or three plugins all screwed up when I updated it and I have to delete the files and database info manually because the delete function in wordpress isn't working. Where is plugin data found in the SQL Database, one of the plugins had its own table(s) that I dropped, but the others do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the plugins stored in the `wp_options` table in your WordPress database. The query I can provide you with would be different based on what you're trying to do.

You'll also want to remove the plugin folders from the file system afterwards.  The folder is located in: `/your-domain/wp-content/plugins`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic answer, every plugins are different.

Comment: Ok that makes things harder. I guess its time to either start picking apart the database for where the plugins create the entries or just digging through every table. Thanks for that answer at least.